# Where should the partitioning column go in the primary key on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

I've got a potentially very large table (potentially hundreds of millions of rows) consisting of the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE (
    date SMALLDATETIME,
    id BIGINT,
    value FLOAT
)
```

which is being partitioned on column `date` in daily partitions.  The question then is should the primary key be on `date, id` or `value, id`?

I can imagine that SQL Server is smart enough to know that it's already partitioning on `date` and therefore, if I'm always querying for whole chunks of days, then I can have it second in the primary key.  Or I can imagine that SQL Server will need that column to be first in the primary key to get the benefit of partitioning.

Can anyone lend some insight into which way the table should be keyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is the standard practice, the Primary Key should be the candidate key that uniquely identifies a given row.

What you wish to do, is known as Aligned Partitioning, which will ensure that the primary key is also split by your partitioning key and stored with the appropriate table data. This is the default behaviour in SQL Server.

For full details, consult the reference [Partitioned Tables and Indexes in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(SQL.90).aspx#sql2k5parti_topic20)

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific need for the partition key to be the first field of any index on the partitioned table, as long as it appears within the index it can then be aligned to the partition scheme.

With that in mind, you should apply the normal rules for index field order supporting the most queries / selectivity of the values.